# Global Navigation drop down menu subsite level

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation

My Sub site Hierarchy is as follows:

```
HOME
    Subsites
        Subsite 1
            Subsite 1a
            Subsite 1b
        Subsite 2
            Subsite 2a
            Subsite 2b
```

The Global Navigation settings for the following subsites are setup as follows:

```
HOME:       Show subsites. 
Max Number of dynamic…: 20
Subsites:   Display the navigation items below the current site
        Show subsites
        Max Number of dynamic…: 20

Subsite 1 and Subsite2:
        Display the same navigation items as the parent site
        Show subsites
        Max Number of dynamic…: 20

All other sub-sub-sub-sites:
        Display the navigation items below the current site
        Show subsites
        Max Number of dynamic…: 2
```

In the MasterPage I have setup the following:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
      ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
      Runat="server"
      EnableViewState="false"
      DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
      AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
      UseSimpleRendering="true"
      UseSeparateCss="false"
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      StaticDisplayLevels="2"
      MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="11"
      SkipLinkText=""
      CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

At the home site, the Subsite menu link has the drop down menu and shows all the subsites and sub-subsites as another level, as intended.
[image]

Subsites, Subsites1, and Subsite 2 have separate menu entries for each one and with their Sub sites. Not what I intended, but it is fine.

[image]

I want each sub-sub-subsite (Subsite1a, Subsite1b, Subsite2a, etc.) to have the the drop down menu as is in the Home site, but be able to add additional entries per site via the Navigation page.

Is this possible?

This is in SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the navigation set to show the parent navigation, then no, you cannot add items via the navigation page. When set to show parent's navigation there's no manual management of the links at that level.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a new masterpage for Subsite 1 and Subsite 2, with a fixed SharePoint:AspMenu object and another controlled by Navigation menu?

Comment: You could do that. We've done a couple solutions where we allow a custom nav provider to augment the OOTB capability.

Comment: Though you may consider using a list to power your "fixed" menu... make it more flexible and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use rest api/jsom to access them.

rest api example

```
http://<site/subsite>/_api/web/navigation/TopNavigationBar

http://<site/subsite>/_api/web/navigation/QuickLaunch
```

then show however you want.